# CSS switcher - looking for more seamless implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a JS CSS switcher to good effect really brilliant. However, I would be delighted if it worked more seamlessly. At the point of opening a new page on the site the default css style often flickers on breifly, before the cookie re-applies the selected CSS style.

e.g. the canvas style is the default style, this opens when first visiting the site, user selects corporate style, they open another page in the site - the canvas style shows for a split second, then the corporate style loads over it. Worse on older computers, but on my main computer this does not often happen on Firefox, although on other browsers, especially Chrome its very noticeable. Does anyone have the expertise to update the workings below with a tweak to say, first check for the cookie, then if no cookie, apply the default style, rather than applying the default style seemingly at the same time?

the code I am using is here below:

in html head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
    {
        // Call stylesheet init so that all stylesheet changing functions 
        // will work.
        $.stylesheetInit();

        // This code loops through the stylesheets when you click the link with 
        // an ID of "toggler" below.
        $('#toggler').bind(
            'click',
            function(e)
            {
                $.switcher();
                return false;
            }
        );

        // When one of the styleswitch links is clicked then switch the stylesheet to
        // the one matching the value of that links rel attribute.
        $('.styleswitch').bind(
            'click',
            function(e)
            {
                $.stylesheetSwitch(this.getAttribute('rel'));
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
);
</script>






<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/canvas.css " title="canvas">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/corporate.css " title="corporate">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/earth.css " title="earth">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/space-and-stars.css " title="space-and-stars">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/under-the-sea.css " title="under-the-sea">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/classical.css " title="classical">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/creative.css " title="creative">
```

the JS

```
(function($)
    {
        // Local vars for toggle
        var availableStylesheets = [];
        var activeStylesheetIndex = 0;

        // To loop through available stylesheets
        $.switcher = function()
        {
            activeStylesheetIndex ++;
            activeStylesheetIndex %= availableStylesheets.length;
            $.stylesheetSwitch(availableStylesheets[activeStylesheetIndex]);
        };

        // To switch to a specific named stylesheet
        $.stylesheetSwitch = function(styleName)
        {
            $('link[@rel*=style][title]').each(
                function(i) 
                {
                    this.disabled = true;
                    if (this.getAttribute('title') == styleName) {
                        this.disabled = false;
                        activeStylesheetIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            );
            createCookie('style', styleName, 365);
        };

        // To initialise the stylesheet with it's 
        $.stylesheetInit = function()
        {
            $('link[rel*=style][title]').each(
                function(i) 
                {
                    availableStylesheets.push(this.getAttribute('title'));
                }
            );
            var c = readCookie('style');
            if (c) {
                $.stylesheetSwitch(c);
            }
        };
    }
)(jQuery);

// cookie functions http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
function createCookie(name,value,days)
{
    if (days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name)
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name)
{
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
// /cookie functions
```

Comment: Could you please highlight (with a very visible comment) where exactly you are switching the entire stylesheet?

Comment: yes its switched in the page with a bunch of a tags: <a class="styleswitch" id="ds1" rel="canvas" title="Set Canvas style">Canvas</a>

Comment: I am confused; the question claims the problem is because there is a flicker when you first open the page when stylesheetSwitch is automatically called (after accessing a cookie). Oh I see, the link is not relevant; what you really want is to move (as my answer suggests) the $stylesheetInit call out of happening before the DOM loads.

Comment: yes I want it happening before the dom loads and with the links still working. I think I understand you and I think you understand me! ... Ive taken away the $(function(){...}) and then put the bits between right at the bottom of the page. the links then work, though i haven't yet done a sitewide change to see if this is the fix for the flickering to stop when loading between pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it server-side...

Anyway, when you do

```
$(function()
{ 
});
```

jQuery waits until the DOM is fully load to execute the function.

So, you should place the javascript just below the `<link />`s section, outside `$(function(){});` . This will make the script as soon as the browsers parses it, and before the page is fully loaded. (it has to be below the  elements because they must be loaded)

Comment: thanks for your answer, please forgive my relative lack of experience, i wouldn't know where to start doing it server side.

Comment: ive removed the function top and bottom bits as suggested, it does load the previously loaded style, however the functionality then to change the style is lost.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear... Only the $.stylesheetInit(); should be outside the $(function(){});. You must keep the rest (i.e., the binds) inside $(function(){});, otherwise they will not be loaded when jQuery tries to find them.

Comment: yes thats what I've just done! It's working and awesome... and the mystery remains of "I would do it server-side"? to keep me inspired to learn more! thanks

Comment: To do server side is basically the same in all languages: store the selected skin in session, and print the call to desired css in runtime (when the page is being processed by the server). The reason for this is that the browser won't download every css file. Not that it make a big difference for you, it's because I design 1 page that works for both desktop and cellphones, which have a slower download speed, so I try to keep downloads to a minimum ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might wish to run your code before the DOM is ready. Perhaps you could run it immediately rather than using $(function(){...}), since jQuery waits until the page loads to execute anything in that (hence the flicker).

Also perhaps this might give insight.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-jquery-before-the-dom-is-ready-12-1-2010

Debugging steps for why links are not working:

```
>>> $('link[@rel*=style][title]') --> seems to show your styles are there
[..., <link rel=​"alternate stylesheet" type=​"text/​css" href=​"/​css/​corporate.css " title=​"corporate">, ...]

>>> $.stylesheetSwitch('corporate') --> seems to work
```

The only problem is that the links are not having anything bound to the onclick; wait... don't you mean this.getAttribute('title')? as you can see above, rel="alternate stylesheet" which is probably not your intent to use as a unique theme identifier.

Comment: im attempting to run the code immediately by removing the $(function(){...}) it seems to work by loading the style i had selected before, but then the ability to change the style is lost

Comment: How is the ability to change the style lost? Are there any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: the links: <a class="styleswitch" id="ds1" rel="canvas" title="Set Canvas style">Canvas</a> to change the style no longer worked, it did however remember the last style selected from when the links did work.

Comment: If you look in your definition of stylesheetInit, it is trying to access availableStylesheets, but if you move it out without also moving out availableStylesheets, it will not have have that variable in its scope.

Comment: I apologize regarding my last comment; I had misread your code slightly. I recommend checking your javascript error console.

Comment: quite alright, i appreciate you taking the time on it. ive been experimenting and the flickering does stop (google chrome) without the function call, but still not got the links working. ive just installed the firefox javascript console and nothings coming up on it. the link is www.delightwebdesign.co.uk if it would help you with diagnosis?

Comment: the not working links are top left of page, its clear to me I'm gonna need a few years study on JS!

Comment: $('link[@rel*=style][title]') seems to show your styles are there; $.stylesheetSwitch('corporate') seems to work; the only problem is that the links are not having anything bound to the onclick; wait... don't you mean this.getAttribute('title')? ---- e.g. <link rel=​"alternate stylesheet" type=​"text/​css" href=​"/​css/​corporate.css " title=​"corporate">​

Comment: i just tried it with the ('title') and no joy, somehow the links works when its inside $(function() { ... }); e.g. the page http://www.delightwebdesign.co.uk/online-request has the "working" code, but without that, the flicker stops but the links no longer work. how bizarre!

Comment: ok im gonna try taking away the function bit for the $.stylesheetInit(); so to resolve flicker and hopefully resolve the canvas breifly loading first, but then put the $('.styleswitch').bind( back in the function bit! ....

Comment: You can use debugging techniques like var x=this.getAttribute('rel'); console.log(x) or alert(x); $.stylesheetSwitch(x);

Comment: awesome! i think that works, ok now gonna put it on multiple pages to check more thoroughly the flicker / canvas briefly loading thing...

Comment: People will appreciate you sharing the solution to the problem. =) Unless... somehow... just adding in the debugging statement made it work... in which case... I quake in terror

Comment: flickering stopped, canvas brief appearance stopped, links working, I'm very happy. What remains are things to learn ... javascript debugging, server-side stuff. basically to understand what on earth and how on earth!. but its working I'm happy. thanks so much for checking it.

Comment: yeah the fix is to take $.stylesheetInit(); out of the $(function() { ... and leave the rest inside it ... for a few hours i was taking away the $(function() completely but its needed for the links.